# Is twig syntax allowed in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, twig

I am currently doing an internship at a company and i encountered a weird looking piece of code that is throwing lots of syntax errors like `')' expected` or `Expression expected`. These syntax errors are present in my text editor at the `if else` statement and the curly brackets for the `current_day` variable. It looks like someone tried to use `Twig` syntax inside of `Javascript` `tags`.

```
{% block scripts %}
  <script>
   {% if current_week == week_number %}
   $('#collapseTable' + {{ current_day }}).collapse('show');
   {% else %}
   $('#collapseTable0').collapse('show');
   {% endif %}
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

I am a complete noob when it comes to `Twig` so i'm not sure if this is something `Javascript` and `Twig` actually allow you to do, it doesn't seem very logical to me after reading some of the documentation, but if it's actually allowed, could there be any way of fixing these syntax errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure it's allowed. Twig is executed server-side and will just generate plain text as output. However the output of the snippet you've posted definitely will generate a syntax error when the variable `current_day` is undefined, null or an empty string:

Template

```js
$('#collapseTable' + {{ current_day }}).collapse('show');
```

Output when `current_day` is undefined, null or empty string:

```js
$('#collapseTable' + ).collapse('show');
```

---

As you didn't provide more information, I can only guess about the solution/use-case

1. Make sure `current_day` is not undefined

This solution requires a (valid) javascript variable to be defined though, lets assume `foo` is assigned to `current_day`, then the output would be:

```js
$('#collapseTable' + foo).collapse('show');
```

This means the (javascript) variable `foo` needs to be defined inside the script. Every non-valid variable name will generate another syntax error though, e.g. `current_day` is `foo bar`:

```
$('#collapseTable' + foo bar).collapse('show');
```

---

2. Move the twig variable inside the selector w/out concatenation inside `JS`

```js
$('#collapseTable{{ current_day }}').collapse('show');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I provided a little more information in my question regarding the syntax errors.

Comment: I've see you added the words `text editor` to the question.  If you are using twig to generate javascript, you should not bother what the text editor states though. It cannot compile twig. You'll have to run the code and watch the output to identify real syntax errors

Comment: the code seems to be working just fine despite the syntax errors in the `text editor`